# Загрузка изображения согласно размеру монитора

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть ли библиотеки которые например по $(window).width или по screen.width позволяют узнать реальный размер монитора, что бы подгрузить изображение (например бэкграунд) именно нужного размера?

Comment: Экрана? Не окна браузера?
Мб:
window.availHeight
window.availWidth

Comment: @uzumaxy, window.screen.availHeight и window.screen.availWidth

Comment: @HappyCougar, используйте media queries. Это будет быстрее.